# Globalize custom control text in code behind using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, globalization

I have a web application which uses the globalization values being passed from sql server 2005 using a ResourceProviderFactory. I can globalize the labels in UI using <%$ Resources: "Resourcekey" %>
however, i wish to know how i can globalize the dynamic/custom controls available in the code behind of my vb.aspx page?

please help me out..thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use GetGlobalResourcesObject(Class, ResourceKey) to do this.
Example, lblHello.Text = GetGlobalReourceObject("GlobalKey", "Hello").ToString()